# Need help to find out this datasheet or similer model parts that can replace with this?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, resistors

Need help to find out this datasheet or similar model parts that can i replace with this...???

i have have a problem with this transistor...this transistor front pin broken from body i want to replace it but i did not find out any salutation .....

its marking code is wrote in up ( N1Z5 ) that u see in the picture... i did not find it any where can any one help me to find its datasheet or similar one that can i replace with this ???[image: 1]]

Comment: need help argent???

Comment: From whatever I searched, it might be an N-channel FET, not sure though. Couldn't find the exact model.

Comment: "*need help argent???*" If you want urgent help then you pay someone. We will answer if we want to, when we want to. Please have some respect.

Comment: I found that model on website but i dont understand will u see it bro??  @Sachin            ...http://www.ic-smd.com/stk/page/1/1HC1-3_11254.html

Comment: @Agent007 we're not your "bros". We're strangers on the internet who are trying to help. Please handle us with a bit of respect, and also, patience. You must also understand that your question is very vague.

Comment: hey @MarcusMüller what do u think about this ''bros'' its a short form of '' brothers '' I did not say anything to you or asked anything so why u Talking forward...I do not care if you are in whatever you are ??? by the way If you think anything in my words, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

### It's a MOSFET

From the codebook data I've been able to find, it's a P-channel MOSFET, either a [Vishay Si2301CDS](http://www.vishay.com/docs/68741/si2301cd.pdf) or an [APEC AP2301GN](http://www.itbaza.ru/datasheet/itbaza.ru_AP2301GN.pdf).  The two parts have roughly comparable specs and are pin/package compatible, so I'd give the Si2301CDS a whirl in the application.

Comment: Brother Can I replace Si2301CDS this model with the top of ???

Comment: @Agent007 -- are you asking if you can *use* the Si2301CDS as a replacement or if you can *substitute* something else for it?

Comment: Yes sir....can i replace (Si2301CDS) Or (AP2301GN) Instead of pic (N1Z5) mosfet ??? @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: @Agent007 -- that's what I'm saying, yes.  Try the Si2301CDS first, it should be easier to get.

Comment: Thanx a lot sir...

Comment: sir i did not get Si2301CDS (A1SHB) model which u suggest me for replace.....but i able to get Si2302DS (A2SHB) which is look like same can i replace Si2302DS (A2SHB) Instead of pic (N1Z5) mosfet ???@ThreePhaseEel

Comment: @Agent007 - the Si2302DS is a NMOS part, so it's *not* a suitable substitute